# add additional style if iPhoneX

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a helper function is.iphone('x') to check for iphone x and I want some styles to get added to the styles.icon and styles.textContainer and styles.container if true. This needs to happen inside the render method. However, when I try to run my code:

```
    const styles = {
  addToCartButton: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    width: windowWidth,
  },
  container: {
    overflow: 'hidden',

  },
  innerContainer: {
    width: 2 * windowWidth,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  checkoutButton: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    width: windowWidth,
  },
  icon: {
    backgroundColor: accentColor,
  },
  textContainer: {},
}

export class CartButton extends Component {
  checkoutButtonColor = new Animated.Value(3)

  xOffset = new Animated.Value(-windowWidth)


  dynamicStyles = {
    transform: [ { translateX: this.xOffset } ],
  }

  checkoutDynamicStyles = {
    backgroundColor: this.checkoutButtonColor.interpolate({
      inputRange: [ 0, 3 ],
      outputRange: [ color('b'), accentColor ],
    }),
  }

  animate = () => {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(this.xOffset, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.checkoutButtonColor, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 250,
        userNativeDriver: true,
      }),
    ]).start()
  }

    )
  }

  render () {
    if (is.iphone('x')) {
      styles.icon.paddingBottom = spacing
      styles.textContainer.paddingBottom = spacing
      styles.container.marginBottom = spacingSizes.large
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={[ styles.innerContainer, this.dynamicStyles ]}>
          {this.renderCheckout()}
          {this.renderAddToCart()}
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I get the error "you are attempting to set Key 'paddingBottom' with value '14' (spacing =14) on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen. How to do this any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code and replace  `style={styles.container}` by `style={[styles.container, is.iphone('x') ? { marginBottom: spacing } : {}]}` and do the same where you use the icon style.